# I found out that a new restaurant has opened

Tags: present-perfect, american-english, british-english, past-simple

On the way home from work, Sarah noticed a new restaurant a couple of blocks from her house. When she came home, she said to her husband:

*1. I **found** out that a new restaurant **has opened** in our neighborhood. We could go there for dinner together tomorrow.*

*2. I **found** out that a new restaurant **opened** in our neighborhood. We could go there for dinner together tomorrow.*

I wonder if the bolded tenses work in this context. Also, would be correct to say that version #1 would be used in British English, whereas both of them can be used in American English? Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't Sarah say what you said? "I **noticed** a new restaurant a couple of blocks away." Saying "I found out" suggests that Sarah did some research on local restaurants, or someone else mentioned it. I would omit the word 'together' too. "We could go" implies 'together' not 'separately', and it makes the sentence clunky. So does repeating the ideas of 'new' and 'has opened'.  I suggest "I noticed a new restaurant in our neighborhood. Let's go there for dinner tomorrow."

Comment: Either could be used. The choice of which to use has nothing to do with British versus American English.  These are just English.  The only obviously American thing in your sentence is the incorrect spelling of neighbourhood. LOL;)

Comment: @BillyKerr: Mind yor p's, q's *and **u's,*** [neighborino!](https://www.cracked.com/article_39235_hi-diddly-ho-neighborino-15-trivia-tidbits-about-ned-flanders.html) :)

Comment: Personally, I would never use the simple past tense in this context unless a time-scale was involved - "a new restaurant opened last week" - but statements like (2) are becoming increasingly common in British English.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them work and both of them convey the same message.

Both of them are said all over the world.

There is only a slight difference of tone however.

#1 conveys that Sarah is very confident that it has not been much time since the restaurant has opened .

#2 conveys that Sarah is somewhat less confident about the time, the restaurant has opened and hence she puts less emphasis on the actual time rather on the event that it has opened.

Comment: Regarding the time since it opened, "a restaurant opened" could be used if the restaurant opened and closed, while "a restaurant has opened" implies it's still open. Obviously from the second sentence, you can infer that the restaurant hasn't shut, but "I found out that a new restaurant opened in our neighborhood. It shut before we could go." is fine.